# String manipulating, What does the following function do?

Tags: c, string

Tried to figured out what exactly is the purpose of the next function?

I understand it is doing some manipulating over string - getting char pointer - command,
checking if there is space or tab space... but at the end I didnt understand what is this function doing?

```
void FixCommand(char* command)
{
    char newCommand[MAX_COMMAND_SIZE + 1];
    char* currChar = command;
    int lastConfirmed = 0;
    int inputIndex = 0;
    while ((*currChar == ' ') || (*currChar == '\t'))
    {
        ++currChar;
    }
    while (*currChar != 0)
    {
        if (*currChar != '\n')
        {
            newCommand[inputIndex] = *currChar;
            ++inputIndex;
            if ((*currChar != ' ') && (*currChar != '\t'))
            {
                lastConfirmed = inputIndex;
            }
        }
        ++currChar;
    }
    newCommand[lastConfirmed] = 0;
    strcpy(command, newCommand);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The program skips the initial spaces/tabs in the `command` string, and then copies all characters into `newCommand[]`, skipping over the "new line" `\n` characters. It also looks for the breaks (spaces or tabs) in the `command` string, makes a note of the last non-blank character that it sees, and marks its position. At the end, the portion of the `command` from the first non-blank to the last non-blank is copied back into the `command`, with `\n` characters removed.

For example, if the incoming command string looks like this:

```
"    quick brown\nfox\tjumps over the\tlazy dog\t "
```

then the output is going to look like this:

```
"quick brownfox\tjumps over the\tlazy dog"
```

The purpose behing it may be to "sanitize" a command string before passing it to an external system that does not allow `\n` and leading/trailing blanks.

Comment: when u write "\n" you mean new line?

Comment: @Yuval Yes, `\n` represents the "new line" character in C.

Comment: but if i operate the function with this string: "      hello \nworld" it earase the first spaces and do nothing with the "\n" in the middle

Comment: @Yuval That's not what I see: [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/75lSnP) - the `\n` gets removed, as it should be.

Comment: very strange, i tried again to invoke the function with"yuval\nyuval"
and it print the same string: "yuval\nyuval". doing nothing with the \n

Comment: @Yuval Do you pass the string on the command line, or from a C code? The `\n` sequence becomes a single "new line" character only in compiled code; on the command line, it remains two characters - \ and n.